# Exchange 2010 install failing on Server 2008

Tags: exchange-2010

I am trying to install Exchange 2010 on a fresh install of Server 2008. I believe I have all of the server roles and features configured properly, however I am getting this error:

---

Summary: 12 item(s). 0 succeeded, 1 failed.
Elapsed time: 00:04:07

Organization Preparation
Failed

Error:
The following error was generated when "$error.Clear();

```
      $acceptedDomains = @{};
      Get-AcceptedDomain | foreach {
          $domainName = $_.DomainName.ToString();
          if ($acceptedDomains.Contains($domainName)) {
              Write-ExchangeSetupLog -Warning "Duplicate AcceptedDomain found.  '$($acceptedDomains[$domainName])' and '$($_.Name)' both reference domain '$domainName'";
          } else {
              $acceptedDomains.Add($domainName, $_.Name);
          };
      };

      function getSmtpTemplates ([string]$property)
      {
          $input |
              Select-Object -ExpandProperty $property |
              Where-Object {$_.PrefixString -eq "SMTP"} |
              Foreach-Object {$_.AddressTemplateString -replace ".*@", ""};
      }


      function addDomains ([Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.SystemConfiguration.AcceptedDomainType]$domainType)
      {
          $domain = $null;
          $input |
              Where-Object {-not $acceptedDomains.ContainsKey($_)} |
              Where-Object {[Microsoft.Exchange.Data.SmtpDomainWithSubdomains]::TryParse($_, [ref] $domain)} |
              Foreach-Object {
                  $name = $domain.ToString();
                  if ($name.Length -gt 64) { $name = $name.Substring(0, 64) };
                  if ($acceptedDomains.ContainsValue($name) ) {$name = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString()};

                  new-AcceptedDomain -Name:$name -DomainName:$domain -DomainType:$domainType;
                  $acceptedDomains[$domain.ToString()] = $name;
              };
      }

      $emailAddressPolicies = Get-EmailAddressPolicy;
      $emailAddressPolicies | getSmtpTemplates "NonAuthoritativeDomains" | addDomains "InternalRelay";
      $emailAddressPolicies | getSmtpTemplates "EnabledEmailAddressTemplates" | addDomains "Authoritative";
    " was run: "The property value is invalid. The value can't contain leading or trailing whitespace. Property Name: Name".
```

The property value is invalid. The value can't contain leading or trailing whitespace. Property Name: Name
Elapsed Time: 00:04:07

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have fixed what I thought was the problem, namely a "\" in the CN= object. Still didn't fix it. I ran exchange health check tool and pre-deployment tool which passed. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Exchange 2003, open Exchange System Manager, navigate to Recipients > Recipient Policies, locate the Recipient Policy (other than the Default) which has a trailing white-space.  Right click the policy and choose Rename, remove the white-space after its name.

This trailing white-space is what's causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was a known issue in Exchange 2007, where the DN in one of your recipient policies contained a rogue whitespace.

Check out this http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233089(EXCHG.80).aspx and see what's in your policies using ADSIedit.

Comment: Hi, and thanks.

when I go to ADSIedit, CN=Services / CN<org name> / there is a rogue "\" character, which indicated a white space. The problem is, I can't edit it because it's owned by the system. That technet article says to edit it using the Exchange Management Console, but the EMC won't even install.

Comment: Can you install the EMC on any other machine (even your own PC?). You should be able to strip the install back to just the EMC.

Comment: Hi George, I stripped the install just to the EMC by using the "custom installation" and only checking "Exchange Management Console." Unfortunately I got the same error. I can see what the issue is (rogue "\" character), but it won't let me resolve it without the EMC. Frustrating! :)

Comment: Is this as an upgrade from 2007? If so do you have a 2007 EMC somewhere?

Comment: No, this is a fresh install of SVR 2008, and brand new Exchange 2010.

But I do have an Exchange Server 2003 currently running on another physical server.

Comment: So you followed the steps exactly as stated in @GeorgeHewitt's link and you get exactly the same error?